# ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([802816])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([6422528]))

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation, torchvision

Referring to my question @ [RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 64, 1, 1], expected input[4, 1, 1080, 1920] to have 64 channels, but got 1 channels instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72567402/runtimeerror-given-groups-1-weight-of-size-64-64-1-1-expected-input4-1/72572490?noredirect=1#comment128203781_72572490), I made the suggested corrections, and resized the images using the following lines of code in "train_unet_GAPs.py" (I'm not sure whether this is the correct way of resizing as this is my first experience dealing with torch):

```
train_tfms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((448,448)), transforms.ToTensor(),
                                     transforms.Normalize(channel_means, channel_stds)])

    val_tfms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((448,448)), transforms.ToTensor(),
                                   transforms.Normalize(channel_means, channel_stds)])

    mask_tfms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((448,448)), transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))])
```

However, now I'm getting the following error:

```
total images = 2410
create resnet101 model
Started training model from epoch 0
Epoch 0:   0% 0/2048 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/Othercomputers/My Laptop/crack_segmentation_khanhha/crack_segmentation-master/train_unet_GAPs.py", line 261, in <module>
    train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, validate, args)
  File "/content/drive/Othercomputers/My Laptop/crack_segmentation_khanhha/crack_segmentation-master/train_unet_GAPs.py", line 123, in train
    loss = criterion(masks_probs_flat, true_masks_flat)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 716, in forward
    reduction=self.reduction)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 3130, in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits
    raise ValueError("Target size ({}) must be the same as input size ({})".format(target.size(), input.size()))
ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([802816])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([6422528]))
Epoch 0:   0% 0/2048 [00:01<?, ?it/s]
```

The factor between the 2 sizes is 8, which I guess is num_classes. However, I don't know where I can correct this in the code.

The folder containing all files is at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14NQdtMXokIixBJ5XizexVECn23Jh9aTM?usp=sharing

**EDIT:**
Here is the code for model definition:

```
class UNetResNet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, encoder_depth, num_classes, num_filters=32, dropout_2d=0.2,
                 pretrained=False, is_deconv=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.dropout_2d = dropout_2d

        if encoder_depth == 34:
            self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet34(pretrained=pretrained)
            bottom_channel_nr = 512
        elif encoder_depth == 101:
            self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet101(pretrained=pretrained)
            bottom_channel_nr = 2048
        elif encoder_depth == 152:
            self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet152(pretrained=pretrained)
            bottom_channel_nr = 2048
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError('only 34, 101, 152 version of Resnet are implemented')

        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)

        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

        #self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(self.encoder.conv1,
        #                           self.encoder.bn1,
        #                           self.encoder.relu,
        #                           self.pool)

        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(1,64,kernel_size=(7,7),stride=(2,2),padding=(3,3),bias=False), # 1 Here is for grayscale images, replace by 3 if you need RGB/BGR
                                   nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
                                   nn.ReLU(),
                                   self.pool
                                )
        
        self.conv2 = self.encoder.layer1

        self.conv3 = self.encoder.layer2

        self.conv4 = self.encoder.layer3

        self.conv5 = self.encoder.layer4

        self.center = DecoderBlockV2(bottom_channel_nr, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8, is_deconv)
        self.dec5 = DecoderBlockV2(bottom_channel_nr + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8, is_deconv)
        self.dec4 = DecoderBlockV2(bottom_channel_nr // 2 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8,
                                   is_deconv)
        self.dec3 = DecoderBlockV2(bottom_channel_nr // 4 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 4 * 2, num_filters * 2,
                                   is_deconv)
        self.dec2 = DecoderBlockV2(bottom_channel_nr // 8 + num_filters * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2,
                                   is_deconv)
        self.dec1 = DecoderBlockV2(num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters, is_deconv)
        self.dec0 = ConvRelu(num_filters, num_filters)
        self.final = nn.Conv2d(num_filters, num_classes, kernel_size=1)
        #self.final = nn.Conv2d(num_filters, 1, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        conv1 = self.conv1(x)
        conv2 = self.conv2(conv1)
        conv3 = self.conv3(conv2)
        conv4 = self.conv4(conv3)
        conv5 = self.conv5(conv4)

        pool = self.pool(conv5)
        center = self.center(pool)

        dec5 = self.dec5(torch.cat([center, conv5], 1))

        dec4 = self.dec4(torch.cat([dec5, conv4], 1))
        dec3 = self.dec3(torch.cat([dec4, conv3], 1))
        dec2 = self.dec2(torch.cat([dec3, conv2], 1))
        dec1 = self.dec1(dec2)
        dec0 = self.dec0(dec1)

        return self.final(F.dropout2d(dec0, p=self.dropout_2d))
```

**EDIT2** - The code in train_unet_GAPs.py

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from unet.unet_transfer import UNet16, UNetResNet
from pathlib import Path
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset, random_split
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
import shutil
from data_loader import ImgDataSet
import os
import argparse
import tqdm
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

class AverageMeter(object):
    """Computes and stores the average and current value"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.val = 0
        self.avg = 0
        self.sum = 0
        self.count = 0

    def update(self, val, n=1):
        self.val = val
        self.sum += val * n
        self.count += n
        self.avg = self.sum / self.count

def create_model(device, type ='vgg16'):
    if type == 'vgg16':
        print('create vgg16 model')
        model = UNet16(pretrained=True)
    elif type == 'resnet101':
        encoder_depth = 101
        num_classes = 8
        print('create resnet101 model')
        model = UNetResNet(encoder_depth=encoder_depth, num_classes=num_classes, pretrained=True)
    elif type == 'resnet34':
        encoder_depth = 34
        num_classes = 8
        print('create resnet34 model')
        model = UNetResNet(encoder_depth=encoder_depth, num_classes=num_classes, pretrained=True)
    else:
        assert False
    model.eval()
    return model.to(device)

def adjust_learning_rate(optimizer, epoch, lr):
    """Sets the learning rate to the initial LR decayed by 10 every 30 epochs"""
    lr = lr * (0.1 ** (epoch // 30))
    for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
        param_group['lr'] = lr

def find_latest_model_path(dir):
    model_paths = []
    epochs = []
    for path in Path(dir).glob('*.pt'):
        if 'epoch' not in path.stem:
            continue
        model_paths.append(path)
        parts = path.stem.split('_')
        epoch = int(parts[-1])
        epochs.append(epoch)

    if len(epochs) > 0:
        epochs = np.array(epochs)
        max_idx = np.argmax(epochs)
        return model_paths[max_idx]
    else:
        return None

def train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, validation, args):

    latest_model_path = find_latest_model_path(args.model_dir)

    best_model_path = os.path.join(*[args.model_dir, 'model_best.pt'])

    if latest_model_path is not None:
        state = torch.load(latest_model_path)
        epoch = state['epoch']
        model.load_state_dict(state['model'])
        epoch = epoch

        #if latest model path does exist, best_model_path should exists as well
        assert Path(best_model_path).exists() == True, f'best model path {best_model_path} does not exist'
        #load the min loss so far
        best_state = torch.load(latest_model_path)
        min_val_los = best_state['valid_loss']

        print(f'Restored model at epoch {epoch}. Min validation loss so far is : {min_val_los}')
        epoch += 1
        print(f'Started training model from epoch {epoch}')
    else:
        print('Started training model from epoch 0')
        epoch = 0
        min_val_los = 9999

    valid_losses = []
    for epoch in range(epoch, args.n_epoch + 1):

        adjust_learning_rate(optimizer, epoch, args.lr)

        tq = tqdm.tqdm(total=(len(train_loader) * args.batch_size))
        tq.set_description(f'Epoch {epoch}')

        losses = AverageMeter()

        model.train()
        for i, (input, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
            input_var  = Variable(input).cuda()
            target_var = Variable(target).cuda()

            masks_pred = model(input_var)

            masks_probs_flat = masks_pred.view(-1)
            true_masks_flat  = target_var.view(-1)
            print(masks_probs_flat.shape, true_masks_flat.shape)

            loss = criterion(masks_probs_flat, true_masks_flat)
            losses.update(loss)
            tq.set_postfix(loss='{:.5f}'.format(losses.avg))
            tq.update(args.batch_size)

            # compute gradient and do SGD step
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        valid_metrics = validation(model, valid_loader, criterion)
        valid_loss = valid_metrics['valid_loss']
        valid_losses.append(valid_loss)
        print(f'\tvalid_loss = {valid_loss:.5f}')
        tq.close()

        #save the model of the current epoch
        epoch_model_path = os.path.join(*[args.model_dir, f'model_epoch_{epoch}.pt'])
        torch.save({
            'model': model.state_dict(),
            'epoch': epoch,
            'valid_loss': valid_loss,
            'train_loss': losses.avg
        }, epoch_model_path)

        if valid_loss < min_val_los:
            min_val_los = valid_loss

            torch.save({
                'model': model.state_dict(),
                'epoch': epoch,
                'valid_loss': valid_loss,
                'train_loss': losses.avg
            }, best_model_path)

def validate(model, val_loader, criterion):
    losses = AverageMeter()
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():

        for i, (input, target) in enumerate(val_loader):
            input_var = Variable(input).cuda()
            target_var = Variable(target).cuda()

            output = model(input_var)
            loss = criterion(output, target_var)

            losses.update(loss.item(), input_var.size(0))

    return {'valid_loss': losses.avg}

def save_check_point(state, is_best, file_name = 'checkpoint.pth.tar'):
    torch.save(state, file_name)
    if is_best:
        shutil.copy(file_name, 'model_best.pth.tar')

def calc_crack_pixel_weight(mask_dir):
    avg_w = 0.0
    n_files = 0
    for path in Path(mask_dir).glob('*.*'):
        n_files += 1
        m = ndimage.imread(path)
        ncrack = np.sum((m > 0)[:])
        w = float(ncrack)/(m.shape[0]*m.shape[1])
        avg_w = avg_w + (1-w)

    avg_w /= float(n_files)

    return avg_w / (1.0 - avg_w)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch ImageNet Training')
    parser.add_argument('-n_epoch', default=10, type=int, metavar='N', help='number of total epochs to run')
    parser.add_argument('-lr', default=0.001, type=float, metavar='LR', help='initial learning rate')
    parser.add_argument('-momentum', default=0.9, type=float, metavar='M', help='momentum')
    parser.add_argument('-print_freq', default=20, type=int, metavar='N', help='print frequency (default: 10)')
    parser.add_argument('-weight_decay', default=1e-4, type=float, metavar='W', help='weight decay (default: 1e-4)')
    parser.add_argument('-batch_size',  default=4, type=int,  help='weight decay (default: 1e-4)')
    #parser.add_argument('-batch_size',  default=2, type=int,  help='weight decay (default: 1e-4)')
    #parser.add_argument('-num_workers', default=4, type=int, help='output dataset directory')
    parser.add_argument('-num_workers', default=2, type=int, help='output dataset directory')

    parser.add_argument('-data_dir',type=str, help='input dataset directory')
    parser.add_argument('-model_dir', type=str, help='output dataset directory')
    parser.add_argument('-model_type', type=str, required=False, default='resnet101', choices=['vgg16', 'resnet101', 'resnet34'])

    args = parser.parse_args()
    os.makedirs(args.model_dir, exist_ok=True)

    DIR_IMG  = os.path.join(args.data_dir, 'images')
    DIR_MASK = os.path.join(args.data_dir, 'masks')

    img_names  = [path.name for path in Path(DIR_IMG).glob('*.jpg')]
    mask_names = [path.name for path in Path(DIR_MASK).glob('*.png')]

    print(f'total images = {len(img_names)}')

    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    model = create_model(device, args.model_type)

    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), args.lr,
                                momentum=args.momentum,
                                weight_decay=args.weight_decay)

    #crack_weight = 0.4*calc_crack_pixel_weight(DIR_MASK)
    #print(f'positive weight: {crack_weight}')
    #criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=torch.Tensor([crack_weight]).to('cuda'))
    criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss().to('cuda')

    #channel_means = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
    #channel_stds  = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
    channel_means = [0.5]
    channel_stds  = [0.5]
    train_tfms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((448,448)), transforms.ToTensor(),
                                     transforms.Normalize(channel_means, channel_stds)])

    val_tfms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((448,448)), transforms.ToTensor(),
                                   transforms.Normalize(channel_means, channel_stds)])

    mask_tfms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((448,448)), transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))])
    '''
    mask_tfms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Lambda(lambda x: x.repeat(3,1,1)),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), std=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
    '''
    dataset = ImgDataSet(img_dir=DIR_IMG, img_fnames=img_names, img_transform=train_tfms, mask_dir=DIR_MASK, mask_fnames=mask_names, mask_transform=mask_tfms)
    train_size = int(0.85*len(dataset))
    valid_size = len(dataset) - train_size
    train_dataset, valid_dataset = random_split(dataset, [train_size, valid_size])

    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, args.batch_size, shuffle=False, pin_memory=torch.cuda.is_available(), num_workers=args.num_workers)
    valid_loader = DataLoader(valid_dataset, args.batch_size, shuffle=False, pin_memory=torch.cuda.is_available(), num_workers=args.num_workers)

    #model.cuda()
    model.to(torch.device("cuda:0"))

    train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, validate, args)
```

Comment: Can you provide your code for the model definition here *in your question in text*?

Comment: @Ivan I edited the question and added the code for the model definition. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the shapes of `masks_probs_flat` and `true_masks_flat`?

Comment: @Ivan I'm not sure. I resize the images and the masks to size 448x448.

Comment: It's not about guessing, can you check their actual shapes?

Comment: Sorry. Now I understand. masks_probs_flat --> torch.Size([6422528]), true_masks_flat --> torch.Size([802816])

Comment: Thank you, now can you show the code that initializes those two tensors?

Comment: `masks_probs_flat = masks_pred.view(-1)
 true_masks_flat  = target_var.view(-1)`

Comment: I provided a link to the folder containing all the code files as well as the dataset in the question. Also, this is a link to the file you're referring to for your easy reference: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14tiZf12xVkhlsmsafh1pyslfWVhedcxX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide the relevant code here, rather showing how `masks_pred` and `target_var` are defined. You understand the issue is how different both tensor shapes are, right?

Comment: Yes, I understand. I edited the question and added the relevant code.